# magento Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart

Tags: magento

What is the significance of 'Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart' value and its 'Use config' Enable in Magento product Edit page ? We have imported some new products to magento but it didn't show at front end, even though the products quantiy is greater than zero and are in 'In stock'. But it is found that when we untick the 'User Config' under 'Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart' the products are now showing at front end.

[image]

Yes. Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart is set to 1.
[image]

Comment: Go to "System > Configuration > Inventory > Product Stock Options", do you have anything set for "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart"?

Comment: Yes. Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart is set to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it is related but I guess you can delete the only row in "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" and see if it helps.

There is no point in setting 1 for all groups anyway, if a cart has less than 1 of everything then it has nothing to sell.  Minimum quantity only has a use when it's more than 1, or a particular product allows decimal quantities.